# Can someone find the error in my proof that if X is compact then it's a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compactness, compact-manifolds

So, the question is let $X$ be a Hausdorff space such that each point of X has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic with an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Show that if $X$ is compact, then $X$ is an $m$-manifold. It's from Munkres' Topology book(section 36). Here is my flawed proof(but I can't see where my mistake is)

Proof: Let $U$ be an open set of $X$. Let $x$ (where $x \in U$) and let $V$ be the neighborhood of $x$ that is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. So, we consider $W = U \cap V$. This is an open set in $V$, so it is homeomorphic to an open subset P of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Let f be the homeomorphism. Since, $\mathbb{R}^{m}$is second countable, there exists a basis element $B$ such that $f(x) \in B \subset P$. So, $x\in f^{-1}(B) \subset W \subset U$. $f^{-1}(B)$ is obviously open by continuity. Since, $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is second countable, if we repeat this procedure for each  open set $U$ of $X$, the collection $f^{-1}(B)$ is going to be countable as well and is a basis. Hence, X is second countable and a manifold.       $\hspace{70mm}$      $\square$

I know my proof is wrong because I didn't use the compactness condition at all. Could someone point out where exactly my proof goes astray and maybe also give a hint towards a correct proof?

Comment: Here $B = B_U$ depends on $U$. Why is the collection of all $f^{-1}(B_U)$ countable?

Comment: @anomaly. Well, the basis elements in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ are countable. Hence, however I choose the $f^{-1}(B)$, they should be countable too right?

Comment: Right, but you're choosing one $B_U$ for each open set $U$. The collection of all $B_U$ is quite large; $X$ contains many open sets. Take $X$ to be a large set, for example, given the discrete topology and treated as a $0$-manifold.

Comment: @anomaly, I agree but the way I was thinking is that even if the collection of open sets U is uncountable, then since the basis elements in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ are countable, so there will probably be some overlaps. As in the same $f^{-1}(B)$ might be inside two different open sets U($U_{1},U_{2}$). Hence, the collection $f^{-1}(B)$ should still be countable. I guess I'm not getting where I'm going wrong, I will need to think about this for a minute.

Comment: @anomaly, I think I get what you are saying. Since, the collection of open sets U might be uncountable then the collection $B_{U}$ might be uncountable too. But, I guess that's because there would be a lot of redundancies, as in some $B_{U}$ would be in two different open sets $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$. I think I can use compactness to bypass this right? Choose finitely many $U$s(which is guaranteed to cover $X$ by compactness) and use that collection of $B_{U}$s instead?

Comment: Right. Note also that you're looking for a basis of $X$, not $\mathbb{R}^m$. The thing that needs to be countable is the set of $f^{-1}(B)$, and both $f$ and $B$ depend on the choice of $U$. In the example of the discrete $0$-manifold above, for example, you can take all $B_U$ to be the same single point $\{*\}$. That doesn't mean that your cover of $X$ is a single point; all the points $f^{-1}(\{*\})$ are different.

Answer (score 3):

By compactness you get a finite open cover $U_1,\ldots, U_k$ of $X$ such that each $U_i$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Thus for each $U_i$ you get a countable family $\mathcal B_i$ of open $B_{i,n} \subset U_i$ such that each open subset of $U_i$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal B_i$. Let $\mathcal B = \bigcup_{i=1}^k \mathcal B_i$. This is a countable set and it is a basis for $X$. To see that, let $V \subset X$ be open. Then the $V_i = V \cap U_i$ are open subsets of $U_i$ and their unon is $V$. Each $V_i$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal B_i$, thus $V$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal B$.

Remark: It would be sufficient to assume that each open cover of $X$ has  a countable subcover. Such spaces $X$ are known a *Lindelöf*.